# cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); Incorrect syntax after ')'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, syntax-error

I have was trying to make a form in Visual Studio that would insert data into my Microsoft sql server and everything was fine until I went to submit data. It said I have an incorrect syntax after the ) in my cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); line.  I looked at other questions that asked a similar question to my question and tried to make changes to my code based off of these answers but I'm still getting the error.  I'm not sure what is wrong.  Please explain thoroughly, I am still a student :)

Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MEL_DEVConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into mel_line(RULENAME, MFG, DESCRIPT, DEVICE, CODE_2D, MODEL, EVALUATION, GOOD_PATH, GOOD_CLEANSE, NON_DEPLOY_PATH, NON_DEPLOY_CLEANSE, CRITICAL_NOTES, GOOD_COSMETICS, GOOD_BOM, GOOD_SPEC, GOOD_THRESHOLD, AUTHORIZED_BY, ACCT_CODE, LINE_STATUS) values('" + RULENAME.Text + "','" + MFG.Text + "','" + DESCRIPT.Text + "','" + DEVICE.Text + "','" + CODE_2D.Text + "','" + MODEL.Text + "','" + EVALUATION.Text + "','" + GOOD_PATH.Text + "','" + GOOD_CLEANSE.Text + "','" + NON_DEPLOY_PATH.Text + "','" + NON_DEPLOY_CLEANSE.Text + "','" + CRITICAL_NOTES.Text + "','" + GOOD_COSMETICS.Text + "','" + GOOD_BOM.Text + "','" + GOOD_SPEC.Text + "','" + GOOD_THRESHOLD.Text + "','" + AUTHORIZED_BY.Text + "','" + ACCT_CODE.Text + "','" + LINE_STATUS.Text + "',) ", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "New Row In MEL Added Successfully!";
    RULENAME.Text = "";
    MFG.Text = "";
    DESCRIPT.Text = "";
    DEVICE.Text = "";
    CODE_2D.Text = "";
    MODEL.Text = "";
    EVALUATION.Text = "";
    GOOD_PATH.Text = "";
    GOOD_CLEANSE.Text = "";
    NON_DEPLOY_PATH.Text = "";
    NON_DEPLOY_CLEANSE.Text = "";
    CRITICAL_NOTES.Text = "";
    GOOD_COSMETICS.Text = "";
    GOOD_BOM.Text = "";
    GOOD_SPEC.Text = "";
    GOOD_THRESHOLD.Text = "";
    AUTHORIZED_BY.Text = "";
    ACCT_CODE.Text = "";
    LINE_STATUS.Text = "";

}
```

}

Comment: Remove the comma before the last close parenthesis  `..LINE_STATUS.Text + "')`

Comment: Do not use string concaternation to build SQL queries: you are open to SQL Injection attacks. [Parameterise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) your queries instead,

Comment: You should really reformat your code before posting it here on SO. This is impossible to view "at a glance" due to the loooong horizontal scrollbar. And definitely follow @Richard's advice:parameterized queries are the way to go.

Comment: Unrelated, but you create and open a connection that you never close. You should look into `using` statements (applying them to your `con`  and `cmd` objects), and/or proper disposal techniques. If you don't need a persistent connection, you should open and close your connection around every functional statement grouping.

Comment: Ah Thank you!  It works now :D

Comment: Thats why I user `cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@Name",value);` [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

I think you don't need `,` at the end of your query since there is no insert value after it in;

```
LINE_STATUS.Text + "',) "
```

part. Just deleting `,` part will solve your problem.

#### But much more important

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MEL_DEVConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   // Set your CommandText with parameter names.
   // Add your parameter name and their values with Add method in your command
   // Open your connection
   // Execute your command
}
```